# discord '>' not supported between instances of 'Context' and 'int'

Tags: python, if-statement, discord, integer, discord.py

When I try to run the command I always get this error message: "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Context' and 'int'"

````
from discord.ext import commands

class clear(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

# Events

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Clear modul started')

# Command

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(ctx, amount=5, max=100, min=1):
        if (amount > max):
            await ctx.send(f"The value is too high! Enter a value `{min}-{max}` between.", delete_after=5)
        elif (amount < min):
            await ctx.send(f"The value is too small! Enter a value `{min}-{max}` between.", delete_after=5)
        else: 
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
            await ctx.send(f"Törölve {amount}", delete_after=5)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(clear(client))```
````

Comment: What is the call that led to this error? I can see it happening is you passed a 'Context' object as the amount.

Comment: You’re missing self

Comment: I do not know. The command works in **main.py** but when I transfer it to a separate file, I get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you're missing `self` in the command

```py
@commands.command()
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5, max=100, min=1):
   ...
```

Comment: That's true. In each function of a class, you should pass a "self".

Comment: Not all functions in a class take `self` argument @electromeow - `classmethod`s, `staticmethod`s and the `__new__` method don't take it

Comment: I know that but I meant nearly all of them. But thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a "self" param like other answer said.
But I also recommend you to define min and max variables in the code block of function, not at the params of the function.
Because people can change the min value to another value. And in this situation, parameter will be a string. You didn't converted them to integer, so it will error.
Never trust your users (;